# ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object in unittest

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, mocking

I have a code that

1. reads the data from CSV,
2. replaces the columns from space to underscore, and
3. replaces nan with None.

```
    def read_file_and_transform(local_file_path):
        """ """
        try:
            data_df = pd.read_csv(local_file_path)

            data_df.columns = data_df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')

            clean_df = data_df.where((pd.notnull(data_df)), None)

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Failure in read file and transform method {}".format(e))
            raise e
```

I am writing a unit test case for these three lines and facing the error with line 3

Here is my test case:

```
class MockPandas:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def read_csv(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ """
        return pd.DataFrame([{"a b": np.nan, "b": 2.33}])

    def notnull(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ """
        return pd.DataFrame([{"a_b": "None", "b": 2.33}])


 @patch("path", MockPandas())
    def test_read_file_and_transform(self):
        """ """
        result = self.obj.read_file_and_transform("/file_path")
        assert result == [{"a": None, "b": 2.33}]
```

The error I am facing is :

```
ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object
```

Can anyone help me here?
Thanks

Comment: I think that `notnull` should return an array of booleans: for every cell in the original data frame - determine if it's not nan (and place `True`/`False` in that value).

See the official documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.notnull.html and an example to outputs: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-notnull/

So you should change the values you return in your mocked version of `notnull`. 

Let me know if this works so I can write a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterK for the inputs here. I understood what you are trying to say and it fixed my issue. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks, @aman-raheja, I'd appreciate it if you can approve my extended answer for better visibility to future readers of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.notnull` returns a new data frame with the same size as the original data frame, where each cell has a boolean value indicating if the respective value is not nan.

Therefore you should change the return value of your mocked version of `notnull` to match the expected return value.

For example, if the original df is:

```
       A       B     C     D
0  Sandy     NaN  20.0  14.8
1   alex  olivia  20.0   3.0
2  brook  terica   7.0   NaN
3  kelly     dan   NaN   2.3
4    NaN  amanda   8.0   6.0
```

Then df.notnull would be:

```
       A      B      C      D
0   True  False   True   True
1   True   True   True   True
2   True   True   True  False
3   True   True  False   True
4  False   True   True   True
```

Panda's notnull documentation can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.notnull.html).